Spring Boot can`t connect to Kafka in Kubernates
Im new in kafka and kubernates. Im using bitnami chart to deploy kafka in my kind cluster kubernetes (on my own server). Im trying to connect to kafka from my spring boot application, that started on my PC.
When im trying to put topic in kafka i get error Node not found.
My helm chart kafka.yaml config
USER-SUPPLIED VALUES:
auth:
  enabled: false
  interBrokerProtocol: PLAINTEXT
externalAccess:
  controller:
    service:
      nodePorts:
      - 30001
      - 30002
      - 30003
      type: NodePort
      useHostIPs: true
  enabled: true
listeners:
  client:
    protocol: PLAINTEXT
persistence:
  enabled: true
  size: 10Gi

My spring boot application config
server:
  port: 9090
spring:
  application:
    name: authentication
  datasource:
    platform: postgres
    url: jdbc:postgresql://192.168.0.105:54321/users-db
    driverClassName: org.postgresql.Driver
    username: admin
    password: srvadmin
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
    show-sql: true
    properties:
      hibernate:
        format_sql: true
  kafka:
    bootstrap-servers:192.168.0.106:30001
token:
  signing:
    key: 53A73E5F1C4E0A2D3B5F2D784E6A1B423D6F247D1F6E5C3A596D635A75327855

When im trying to send data to kafka, i get "Node may not be avalible"

Don't use IP addresses in k8s https://strimzi.io/blog/2019/04/17/accessing-kafka-part-1/

Am i shoud import my app in k8s, and use dns?

Your app is already in k8s by using Helm, no? Otherwise, you need to setup an Ingress Controller, rather than using IPs and NodePorts
